# How to get Path for local mp3 file from www in Phonegap IOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am using phonegap audio plugin in my phonegap app.
I have some audio files stored in www/audio folder.

For android i used **"file:///android_asset/www/audio"** to read local file.

For IOS i need help.

Thanks

Comment: may be the [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945375/phonegap-ios-how-to-get-app-documents-folder-full-path) support you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playing local sound in phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438822/playing-local-sound-in-phonegap)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally got it,
reference:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438822/playing-local-sound-in-phonegap)

To get path i used this function

```
function getPhoneGapPath() {
   var path = window.location.pathname;
   path = path.substr( path, path.length - 10 );
   return path;
};
```

### USAGE:

For **IOS**:

var snd = new Media( **getPhoneGapPath()** + 'test.mp3' );

For **Android**:**prepend** 'file://'

var snd = new Media( **'file://' + getPhoneGapPath()** + 'test.mp3' );

Answer (score 4):

You will have trouble if called from a file other than 'index.html' because the part to trim off might not be 10 chars.

Try this:

```
// Get absolute file path on the device.
function getPhoneGapPath() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var sizefilename = path.length - (path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    path = path.substr( path, path.length - sizefilename );
    return path;
};
```

Comment: This is great for dealing with unexpected path sizes. This is a better method to get the path than subtracting a fixed length of 10.

Comment: In case the app name contains unicode characters which are encoded into %NN in the window-location-pathname, you will have to turn it back into unicode using `path = decodeURIComponent(path)`