# Sound plays in PhoneGap when testing with phonegap app, but not when built with PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, cordova, audio

I am working on my first android app where you hit a button and it plays a .wav sound, it works great when I run the phonegap server app to test it but then when I package it as an .APK with phonegap build and install it on my phone, it does not play the .wav sounds.

```
$('.sound1').on('touchstart', function () {

var thissound = new Audio();
thissound.src = $(this).attr('key');
thissound.play();   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes I made were instead of new audio(); I did new Media(); and after reading [Playing Local Sound In Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438822/playing-local-sound-in-phonegap) I found out it may have had something to do with the path needing to be an absolute local path, it works in the real packaged app now. I also discovered you need too use [media.release();](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/cordova/media/media.html#media.release) because of the [finite number of times you can play a sound.](http://www.telerik.com/forums/cordova-media-object-loads-sound-and-stops-playing-after-29-times-of-load-)

```
$('.sound1').on('touchstart', function () {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substr( path, path.length - 10 );
    var finalpath = 'file://' + path;
    var key = $(this).attr('key');
    var thissound = new Media( finalpath + key, function onSuccess() {
    // release the media resource once finished playing
    thissound.release();
    } );
    thissound.play();
});
```